# setImageResource

Tags: java, android, imageview

```
int i = 1;
String IMG = "pic";
IMG = IMG + Integer.toString(i);
i = i + 1;   

imageview1.setImageResource(R.drawable.IMG);
```

R.drawable.IMG where IMG is a variable.

This is wrong. What would the right way? I want to change a imageview from pic1 to picN.

---

int[] images = new int[]{R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, R.drawable.pic3};

This is better, but How can I insert a vector element into a imageview?
Sorry for my bad english level :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identifiers that identify the resources in your app are not a series of sequential numbers. Create an array of the images you've added, e.g.

```
int[] images = new int[]{R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, R.drawable.pic3};
```

and increment the index in that instead?

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished by using

```
int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("pic" + i, "drawable", getPackageName());

imageview1.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

This is proven to be fairly slow. A better option might be to keep an array of your drawable IDs and loop through that..

```
int[] drawables = new int[] { R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2 };
```

Comment: how to insert an element of the vector in the imageview?

Comment: imageview1.setImageResource(drawable[i]);

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the solution given by @dymmeh 
You could do this also with Java Reflection but I have a suspicion it can be slow, too.

```
int resId = R.drawable.getClass().getField("pic" + i).getInt(R.drawable);
```